# How can we write a Rundeck plugin which contains both client and server side changes?

Tags: plugins, rundeck

With Rundeck UI plugin we can just call js scripts. is there any way to interact with server side .

My requirement is to call a java and display its output in rundeck UI in a desired location. How to achieve both ?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to take a look at [Rundeck Java Plugin Development](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/tutorials/java-plugin.html). [Here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/tree/master/examples) you've some examples of that kind of plugin.